# Resource dictionary cannot be found?

Tags: wpf, xaml, syncfusion

At least I think this is the problem...

I have a project structured like so (files omitted for brevity)

```
Project
  Assets
    ResourceDictionaries
       Styles.xaml
  MainWindow.xaml
```

I am referencing the resource dictionary as follows in MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ResourceDictionaries/Styles.xaml"/>
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
<Window.Resources/>
```

But none of the styles are being applied to any elements.

I've checked the Build Action is set to page. I've also tried giving some styles in the dictionary a key, but Blend cannot 'see' these keys.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Relevant code. Obviously if I put the properties on the actual elements they work, but in a dictionary they don't:

**MainWindowStyles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.Client.Assets.ResourceDictionaries"
                    xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpf:RibbonWindow}">
        <Setter Property="wpf:SkinStorage.VisualStyle" Value="Office2010Silver"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpf:Ribbon}">
        <Setter Property="BackStageColor" Value="#622166"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<wpf:RibbonWindow x:Class="Company.Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <wpf:RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ResourceDictionaries/MainWindowStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </wpf:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <wpf:Ribbon BackStageHeader="DB">
            <wpf:Ribbon.BackStage>
                <wpf:Backstage>
                    <wpf:BackStageCommandButton Header="Save"/>
                </wpf:Backstage>
            </wpf:Ribbon.BackStage>
        </wpf:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</wpf:RibbonWindow>
```

**Edit 2:**
This is what has been tried so far:

- Tried applying styles to normal controls (Button, Label, etc.). Works
- Tried adding the styles under `<wpf:MainWindow.Resources>`. Doesn't work
- Tried a pack URI. Doesn't work
- Adding the styles/properties to the actual elements. Works (obviously)

Comment: everything is fine. also show your resdictionary plz.

Comment: Question has been amended.

Comment: plz check if your dictionary is working with normal buttons/grids etc.

Comment: Works with normal buttons and controls.

Comment: now check if you current styles work if you define them directly in your MainWindow Resources, and avoid dictionary.

Comment: No. If they're defined under `<MainWindow.Resources>` the styles are not applied.

Comment: its not MainWindow.Resources, but <wpf:RibbonWindow.Resources> in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried these two steps:

- Add MainWindowStyles.xaml to Application.Resources section in app.xaml
- Use explicit style for RibbonWindow, like this:

  ```
  <RibbonWindow>
  ...
  <RibbonWindow.Style>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="RadRibbonWindowStyle"/>
  <RibbonWindow.Style>
  ```

Comment: I'll check that in a moment. I'll update if it works.

Comment: Just checked, doesn't work. I think this library might be the problem rather than the actual dictionary.

Comment: You did added Key attribute to the resource, didn't you? Do you see any resource related errors in the VS' Output window?

Comment: There is also some info here on Syncfusion's site - http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/ribbon/stylingandtemplates

Comment: Yeah I added the key, but then when the application loads the window is blank. I'll check that documentation just in case I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Ok, I've tried setting the Resource Dictionary to `<ResourceDictionary Source="/Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf;Component/FrameWork/Ribbon/themes/Office2010Silver.xaml"/>` but it says 'An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "/Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf;Component/Framework/Ribbon/themes/Office2010Silver.xaml"'.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added reference to Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf assembly and set 'Copy to Local' to True? You might want to use a tool like dotPeek to check the assembly for proper resource path. Mind the case, btw.

Comment: Yeah I've got dotPeek open now, just trying to figure out where to look.

Comment: Assembly - Resources - something.g.resources. Anything below is a path you need to put into Source attribute, right after component/. Working example for Telerik is this:

                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml" />

Comment: Well I'm doing something right now. The BackStage colour is still yellow though but I'm not getting any errors or exceptions. I'll keep tinkering until I find something.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx) syntax:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Assets/ResourceDictionaries/Styles.xaml"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. As an aside, if I right click on the pack URI in blend and click ''Go to definition' that should open the resource dictionary file in a new tab, right?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to supplement the [accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724714/1405500)

My code now looks like this. I didn't manage to get it to work with the `VisualStyle` property, but this will do. If anyone does know how to get that into a Resource Dictionary though, the help would be much appreciated. :)

Long story short, this is the code that works based on the exchange between me and @AlexSeleznyov

**MainWindowStyles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf;component/framework/ribbon/themes/office2010silverstyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="MainRibbon" TargetType="{x:Type wpf:Ribbon}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Office2010SilverRibbonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="BackStageColor" Value="#622166"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<wpf:RibbonWindow x:Class="Company.Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Company.Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        wpf:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Office2010Silver"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800"
        Icon="Assets/Icons/ApplicationIcon.ico">
    <wpf:RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ResourceDictionaries/MainWindowStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </wpf:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <wpf:Ribbon BackStageHeader="File" Style="{StaticResource MainRibbon}">
            <wpf:Ribbon.BackStage>
                <wpf:Backstage>
                    <wpf:BackStageCommandButton Header="Save"/>
                </wpf:Backstage>
            </wpf:Ribbon.BackStage>
        </wpf:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</wpf:RibbonWindow>
```